# Objective C Encapsulation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I will explain my question from an example.

In .H file//

```
@interface Employee:NSObject{

@private

NSString *name;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
```

in .M file//

```
@implementation{

@synthesize name;

}
```

In this scenario when i access the name property within another class , like `myEmp.Name = @"John";`
it doesn't raise any issue. Does this according to the encapsulation rules or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't aware of that. :-)

Comment: Hi..Have you got exact idea about encapsulation in iOS? In your example can we say it is example of encapsulation for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, only an instance method of object can access an instance variable. There is no way for an external object to access the instance variables of an object directly. The `@private` is only relevant to inheritance.

To make the variables accessable there are properties. A property defines a method, and methods on Objective-C are all public. There is no way in Objective-C do define private methods, you can only "hide" them by declaring them somewhere else than the public .h file (e.g. inside the .m file via `@interface Employee()` which declares an anonymous section).

Comment: It is trivially easy to access ivars directly from external objects, regardless of the presence or absence of `@private`.

Comment: @bbum: You're right, I was assuming that Objective-C behaves the same as Ruby here...

Answer (score 7):

You did not break encapsulation rules, because the `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;` already indicates you want to expose the getters/setters for `name`.

Encapsulation is broken only when you access the ivar directly, i.e.

```
myEmp->name = @"John";  // wrong
```

Comment: If there are no properties for data in the class, using the object->ivarName would be the only way to access ivars in an isEqualTo method .

Answer (score 5):

I think you have misunderstood what @property and @synthesize are for. They are convenience ways to define accessor methods. ie. what you have is equivalent to:-

```
- (NSString *)name;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)value;
```

`myEmp.name = @"John"` is syntactic sugar for `[myEmp setName:@"John"]`

So you explicitly created optional public accessor methods and then used them. No encapsulation broken here.